# Python, Foor Loop with Append

Tags: python, for-loop

```
five_elements=[["Albuquerque","749"],["Anaheim","371"],["Anchorage","828"],["Arlington","503"],["Atlanta","1379"]]

crime_rates = []
for row in five_elements:
    crime_rate = row[1]
    crime_rates.append(crime_rate)
    print(crime_rates)
```

**Why is it showing 749 more than once? How is the Loop working here?**

**how can I fix my code so it shows this line only** `['749', '371', '828', '503', '1379']`

Comment: If you want it to print only once at the end of the loop, you should ident the `print(crime_rates)` in the same you you indented the `for`

Comment: You print `crime_rates` every single time you iterate over `five_elements`. Also there is a missing comma in `five_elements` between indexes 2 and 3.

Comment: You can also use list comprehension `print([element[1] for element in five_elements])`

Answer (score 1):

I think this should get the job done :

```
five_elements=[["Albuquerque","749"],["Anaheim","371"],["Anchorage","828"],
["Arlington","503"],["Atlanta","1379"]]
crime_rates = []
for row in five_elements:
    crime_rate = row[1]
    crime_rates.append(crime_rate)
print(crime_rates)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
five_elements=[["Albuquerque","749"],["Anaheim","371"],["Anchorage","828"],["Arlington","503"],["Atlanta","1379"]]

new_data = [i[-1] for i in five_elements]
```

Comment: it does not answer the first question nor explain what is a list-comprehension